# Getting Date range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I want to get a date range having start and end date

I have implemented something like this:

```
from datetime import date
start = date("2012-01-15")
end = date("2012-09-20")
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='M').shift(15, freq=pd.datetools.day)
```

But I am getting an Error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: `start = "2012-01-15"
end = "2012-09-20"
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='M').shift(15, freq='D')` ? `date()` expects a tuple `date(2012,1,15)`.

Comment: Per [`pd.date_range`  docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range)... "start : str or datetime-like, optional
Left bound for generating dates.

end : str or datetime-like, optional
Right bound for generating dates."  So, it accepts string or dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datetime module does not recognize strings, convert them into integers, in the format of date(*year*, *month*, *day*)

```
start = date(2012, 1, 15)
end = date(2012, 9, 20)
```

Edit: lose the 0 for single digits